# Magic for the mute?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter, if charms will work and wands will shoot out things only on uttering spells, then it is almost impossible for mute people to survive as a part of the magical community.

Is there a way in which even the mutes can perform magical charms, with the help of anything else?

Comment: I think the word you're after is "mute"...

Comment: @JonClements - Moot point.

Comment: Why not just get someone to magic you a voice? A certain person managed to make a body from a fragment of a soul, so it isn't too far fetched

Answer (score 0):

One might suppose there are devices that can cause a person's thoughts to become spoken, but it'd be a question whether or not magically-generated words could be used for magic.

There's also a possibility that with all the advances in magical medicine, being mute could be one of the things they can fix.  They can't fix sight issues (all the wizards with glasses) but they might have something for a blow to the larynx.

Comment: Look up "non-verbal spells."

Comment: Also, "one might suppose" and "also a possibility" = "I'm totally guessing".

Comment: @JohnP Sure but at the same time since nobody in canon is mute all other answers are guessing, too, if you want to be technical...Yes it might be weaker unspoken but Dumbledore and Voldemort put powerful silent spells out that there is no evidence that it was meant to be silent. Powerful wizards or not is irrelevant here. If we don't have an example it's hard to analyse and if we can't analyse then how can you say anything for certain?

Comment: I'm sure if we ask JK she'd whistle up an answer for us, and pretend it was that way all along - " 'Silent' Abe Crabbington, Hufflepuff, class of '98, used a dictation necklace, but got in trouble when he forgot to turn it off when walking past the girls' gymnasium"

Answer (score 0):

In *Half-Blood Prince*, they were learning about wordless casting, so that could be a possibility as to how a mute could cast charms/spells.

According to canon, unless a spell is designed for non-verbal use, it will be weaker than the verbal usage, so that could be quite an impediment